# PHP, MySQL select, order by field and group it

Tags: php, mysql, select, subquery, sql-order-by

Welcome!

I have a problem with my SQL query.

Each of my users has a unique table with viewed tags. I want to show him what he can arouse his interest, but I can not cope with the query to the database...

User X has tags:

```
tag_id 8 viewed 150 times
tag_id 11 viewed 100 times
tag_id 12 viewed 80 times
```

Here's **my QUERY**:

```
SELECT c.id AS cid, c.value, t.id AS tag_id, t.value AS tag_name 
FROM components c 
JOIN connect_tag_com ctc ON ctc.component_id = c.id 
JOIN tags t ON t.id = ctc.tag_id 
WHERE t.id IN('8', '11', '12') 
ORDER BY FIELD (t.id, '8', '11', '12') ASC, c.id DESC
```

To this database: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/904d1a/6

Result:

```
| id |                   value | id |      value |
|----|-------------------------|----|------------|
|  8 | article about beetroots |  8 | refreshing |
|  7 |     article about pears |  8 | refreshing |
|  5 |    article about apples |  8 | refreshing |
|  4 |  article about cucumber |  8 | refreshing |
|  1 |   article about carrots |  8 | refreshing |
|  8 | article about beetroots | 11 |      sweet |
|  7 |     article about pears | 11 |      sweet |
|  6 |   article about berries | 11 |      sweet |
|  3 |   article about bananas | 11 |      sweet |
|  1 |   article about carrots | 11 |      sweet |
|  8 | article about beetroots | 12 | wegetables |
|  4 |  article about cucumber | 12 | wegetables |
|  2 |    article about onions | 12 | wegetables |
|  1 |   article about carrots | 12 | wegetables |
```

Now remains me only group by c.id component which unfortunately destroys the whole philosophy, because the task of the query is finding materials in my order of watched tags. So if **c.id 4** has **tags 8 and 12**, as a result of the query should receive **c.id 4** only tagged with the searched first, **tag 8**. Second tag - **12** be omitted.

You get it?

Thats what i talking about:

For TAGS: 8, 11, 12

```
|c.id|                   value |t.id|      value |
|----|-------------------------|----|------------|
|  8 | article about beetroots |  8 | refreshing |
|  7 |     article about pears |  8 | refreshing |
|  5 |    article about apples |  8 | refreshing |
|  4 |  article about cucumber |  8 | refreshing |
|  1 |   article about carrots |  8 | refreshing |
|  6 |   article about berries | 11 |      sweet |
|  3 |   article about bananas | 11 |      sweet |
|  2 |    article about onions | 12 | wegetables |
```

Only unique ID. I know I can do it with SUBQUERY, but I do not know how to do it. Can you help?

Have nice day!

Comment: I don't understand :-(

Comment: Knew it :) I want to get a unique c.ID in order t.ID. If c.ID was selected earlier, skipping it further. Each c.ID can have several tags if the tag again later to go skipping, and ascribe only the first time. Now u get it? Please analyze the attached tables above. Thanks!

Comment: Nope. I still don't understand. Can you summarize in polish?

Comment: Potrzebuję wybrać z bazy artykuły wg. popularności tagu. Np. userX oglądał artykuły najczęściej z tagami: 8, 11 i 12, teraz chcę z bazy wybrać artykuły wg właśnie tej kolejności. Zatem najpierw artykuły z tagiem 8, później (bez powtórzeń ID) tag 11 i na koniec artykuły z tagiem 12. Jeśli artykuł posiada tag 8 i 11, to wybieram go z tagiem 8, a z 11 pomijam. Tak jakby sortuję go wg. priorytetów jakie posiadam. Podsumowując, potrzebuję wybrać z listy artykuły w kolejności zainteresowania tagiem.

Comment: Ah, ok - I get it now. Somehow I couldn't see what you meant by repetition before. Could there be more than 3 tags selected?

Comment: Each article can have an unlimited number of tags

Comment: Ok,  but can a user search for more than 3 tags simultaneously?

Comment: Yes its unlimited too.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure that there are more subqueries here than are strictly necessary, but for some reason I cannot get it to work without them...

```
SELECT cid
     , value
     , tag_id
     , tag_name
  FROM 
     ( SELECT cid
     , value
     , tag_id
     , tag_name
     , CASE WHEN @prev = cid THEN @i:=@i+1 ELSE @i:=1 END i
     , @prev := cid
  FROM 
     ( SELECT c.id cid
            , c.value
            , t.id tag_id
            , t.value tag_name 
         FROM components c
         JOIN connect_tag_com ctc 
           ON ctc.component_id = c.id 
         JOIN tags t 
           ON t.id = ctc.tag_id 
        WHERE t.id IN(8,11,12)
     ) x
  JOIN ( SELECT @prev:=null,@i:=0 ) vars
 ORDER 
    BY value
     , FIELD(tag_id,8,11,12) ASC
     ) n
  WHERE i = 1  ORDER 
    BY FIELD(tag_id,8,11,12) ASC
     , value;
```